# Is resultant power in a series circuit equal to sum of the individual powers?

Tags: electricity

This is what I did. Is this correct?
V=V1+V2
As current in series circuit is constant,
VI=V1I+V2 I
Therefore, P=P1+P2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is indeed correct. You would have to multiply the current by the individual voltage of each component as current is the same throughout the circuit. What you did is correct!

Answer (score 0):

If P is intended to mean power in watts, then it is only correct if the two voltage drops are across resistors, as only resistors dissipate real power in watts. It would not be true if the circuit elements were ideal capacitors and inductors. In that case VxI is apparent power in volt-amperes.

Hope this helps.